# Row and column from "Itemchanged" signal

Tags: python-2.7, qtablewidget

I'm working with the "itemchanged" signal.
How can I find out the row and column where the item was changed?
I only found the same question for c++, but I'm using python.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The slot you connect to the `itemChanged()` signal receives a reference to the `QTableWidgetItem` that changed. You should be able to call the `row()` and `column()` functions of this object to determine the row/column.  For example, the code to register your slot might look like this:

```
self.imagesTable.itemChanged.connect(self.changeIcon)
```

and the function registered might look like this:

```
def changeIcon(self, item):
    row = item.row()
    col = item.column()
     ...
```

Comment: im new to python, sry... but how exactly can i call the row() function? can you give me a little example?  i have `self.model.itemChanged.connect(self.test)`what comes into the "test"-function?